# Ruby class instance and inheritance

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I want to make a subclass to add attributes to the subclass in addition to the superclass.  this is what I've tried:

### Version I:

```
class Person
    attr_reader :first_name, :last_name, :age
    def initialize (first_name, last_name, age) 
        @first_name = first_name  
        @last_name = last_name
        @age = age
    end
end

class Musician < Person
    attr_reader :first_name, :last_name, :age, :instrument
    def initialize (first_name, last_name, age, instrument)
        super 
        @instrument
    end
end
```

---

### Version II

```
class Person
    ATTRS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age']
    def attributes
        ATTRS
    end
end

class Musician < Person
    ATTRS = ['instrument']
    def attributes
        super + ATTRS
    end
end
```

---

Neither of these work.

Comment: In future, can you give the error message, rather than say "it doesn't work"?

Answer (score 2):

In version 1 try

```
class Musician < Person
  attr_reader :instrument
  def initialize(first_name, last_name, age, instrument)
     # Pass arguments to the super class' constructor!
     super first_name, last_name, age
     @instrument = instrument
  end
end
```

Thanks to `attr_reader :first_name, :last_name, :age` in `Person` `Musician` will have those three accessors available because of inheritance.